# Problem with PStricks (Pst-node)

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pst-node

I have problem with the usage of PStricks. When I download the example file from here

https://tug.org/PSTricks/pst-node/Examples/fnode.tex

and compile it by Xelatex, it is strange that I can not get the expected output under the version
of Miktex 2.9 ( installed by basic-miktex-20.11-x64.exe) but the old version is OK. The first image is correct but the second one is not OK.

[image: first imange]

[image: Incorrect output]

How to fix this in the new version of Miktex ?

More worst output as newly upgrades have done (by xelatex):

[image: collect output]
[image: incorrect version]

Of course, we can use pdflatex --shell -escape *.tex +loading **auto-pst-pdf** to get the expected output.

[Log-file added] Sorry, I don't know how to attach the log file.

### I have tried to run the sample file on 4 PCs and NBs, two of them (PCs) are OK but the rest ones (NBs) are not. Here is the log file.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.12.13)  13 DEC 2020 22:21
entering extended mode
**./fnode.tex
(fnode.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count173
\c@section=\count174
\c@subsection=\count175
\c@subsubsection=\count176
\c@paragraph=\count177
\c@subparagraph=\count178
\c@figure=\count179
\c@table=\count180
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2020/06/11 v0.70 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2020/08/26 v5.0i Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count181
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count182
\pstFP@xia=\count183
\pstFP@xib=\count184
\pstFP@xfa=\count185
\pstFP@xfb=\count186
\pstFP@rega=\count187
\pstFP@regb=\count188
\pstFP@regs=\count189
\pstFP@times=\count190
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen139
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen140

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Loading pgffor.code.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex"
\pgf@x=\dimen141
\pgf@xa=\dimen142
\pgf@xb=\dimen143
\pgf@xc=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@ya=\dimen146
\pgf@yb=\dimen147
\pgf@yc=\dimen148
\c@pgf@counta=\count191
\c@pgf@countb=\count192
\c@pgf@countc=\count193
\c@pgf@countd=\count194
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count195
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count196
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen149
\pgfmath@count=\count197
\pgfmath@box=\box47
\pgfmath@toks=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks23
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count198
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen150
\pgffor@skip=\dimen151
\pgffor@stack=\toks24
\pgffor@toks=\toks25
)
\psLoopIndex=\count199

`PSTricks' v3.01  <2020/09/18> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen152
\pst@dimb=\dimen153
\pst@dimc=\dimen154
\pst@dimd=\dimen155
\pst@dimg=\dimen156
\pst@dimh=\dimen157
\pst@dimm=\dimen158
\pst@dimn=\dimen159
\pst@dimo=\dimen160
\pst@dimp=\dimen161
\pst@hbox=\box48
\pst@ibox=\box49
\pst@boxg=\box50
\pst@cnta=\count266
\pst@cntb=\count267
\pst@cntc=\count268
\pst@cntd=\count269
\pst@cntg=\count270
\pst@cnth=\count271
\pst@cntm=\count272
\pst@cntn=\count273
\pst@cnto=\count274
\pst@cntp=\count275
\@zero=\count276
\pst@toks=\toks26
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstricks.con"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"))
\psunit=\dimen162
\psxunit=\dimen163
\psyunit=\dimen164
\pst@C@@rType=\count277
\pslinewidth=\dimen165
\psk@startLW=\dimen166
\psk@endLW=\dimen167
\pst@customdefs=\toks27
\pslinearc=\dimen168
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen169
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen170
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen171
\everypsbox=\toks28
\psframesep=\dimen172
\pslabelsep=\dimen173
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen174
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen175
\pst@shift=\dimen176

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstricks.con"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))
File: pstricks.tex 2020/09/18 v3.01 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2020/09/18 v3.01 `PST-fp' (hv)

>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks-xetex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pst-node\pst-node.sty"
Package: pst-node 2012/09/18 v1.01 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-node' (HV)
Package: pst-node 2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-node\pst-node.tex"
 v1.42a, 2020/04/01
\psrow=\count278
\pscol=\count279
\psmatrixcnt=\count280
\psrowsep=\skip49
\pscolsep=\skip50
\pst@args=\count281
\num@pts=\count282
\pst@argcnt=\count283
)
File: pst-node.tex 2020/04/01 1.42a `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def"
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count284
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count285
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count286
)
(fnode.aux)
\openout1 = `fnode.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <17.28> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 23.
 [1

]
(fnode.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8446 strings out of 413970
 150807 string characters out of 2878318
 435728 words of memory out of 90161446
 27917 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 405273 words of font info for 35 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 58i,5n,64p,559b,255s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on fnode.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: looks okay here. Is your miktex up-to-date? Did you check for updates?

Comment: Yes, I have kept the two PC with different version of Miktex up-to-date. One is just update from the old version (basic-miktex-2.9.7269-x64.exe), the rest one is newly installed by current version (basic-miktex-20.11-x64.exe). I only do not update the package xkeyval which causes crashes in compiling.

Comment: show the log-file.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to attach the log file. I just append it in the original post. I also made tests on the other PC and NB. Still have problem.

Comment: hm, it works fine for me (with xelatex). The only obvious difference I see in the log is that I have newer xkeyval. Check for updates. BTW: you should use @UlrikeFischer to ping me, or will not see if you answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  : Thanks. I will try to update xkeyval in one of my PCs to see whether this is a solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I just update the newly updates (including xkeyval) but it still keeps the same output. At least I know the xkeyval won't cause crashes anymore.

Comment: Compile the fnode file with xelatex, and then make the pdf available somewhere for  check.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I put the pdf file here : https://tinyurl.com/ya5943af.

Comment: hm. I see the problem, but I see nothing that would explain it, you have the same xdvipdfmx version that I have in miktex. Did you configure miktex in some special way? I see e.g. that you are using more memory. Did you do something in dvipdfmx.cfg for example to use another ghostscript?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I don't make any change in dvipdfmx.cfg. I will try to check a copy of the file later. I only use the command "initexmf --admin --edit-config-file=*" to add the following settings : "extra_mem_top = 2000000//main_memory=90000000//save_size=80000" in the *.ini files. *={pdflatex,xelatex,latex} for tikz3d plot. Whether this is main reason for this problem. I do not remember any other

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : I do not remember any change in miktex. I also compare the dvipdfmx.cfg files in two files. They are the same (all blank).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example does not work with `xelatex` and current `xdvipdfmx`.It has some problems with nodes. Use the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or run `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` instead with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{dimen=middle,subgriddiv=0,griddots=5}
\begin{pspicture}(7,7)\psgrid
  [...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. The first one works fine. The second one with package "auto-pst-pdf"  generates a file with fnode-autoapp.pdf instead of fnode.pdf. Hope this problem will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: did you used `pdflatex` with the option`--shell-escape`??  For MikTeX `enable-write18` is also possible.

Comment: I have tried both and they work as I use "\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}" instead. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, then you do not have a Perl installed.